# post value to last row in column A and another value to column F same row as posted in Column A

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to post a value to the last row on column A, then another value to column F in the same row however there might be empty space above that one. How would I go about accomplishing that?

This is what I have so far.

```
Sub test411()

  Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
  Dim sEntity As String, sEnt2 As String, sVal1 As Integer
  Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
  Dim wsUp As Worksheet
  Set wsEntry = Worksheets("Entries")
  Set wsUp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Dim lastrow As Long

  For iRow = 6 To 7
    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    wsEntry.Activate
    iCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsEntry.Range(Cells(iRow, 4), Cells(iRow, 11)), ">0")
    sEntity = wsEntry.Cells(5, 4).Value
    wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1, "A" & lastrow + iCount).Value = sEntity

    For iCol = 5 To 11
      If Cells(iRow, iCol) > "0" Then
        sEnt2 = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
        sVal1 = wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        lastrow = wsUp.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1, "A" & lastrow + 2).Value = sEnt2
        wsUp.Cells("I", lastrow).Value = sVal1
      End If

    Next iCol

  Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code work? You need to qualify `Rows.Count` with the sheet you want it to run on, otherwise it'll run on the activesheet. So I assume you want `lastrow = wsUp.Cells(wsUp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: I have udpated the code to include all of it.  So the part that is not working is sVal1.

Comment: Can you do a while loop? Can you demonstrate an example and add screenshots?

Comment: And what is the value of `wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value` when you get the error? Maybe the value is greater than 2,147,483,647 or smaller than -2,147,483,648? Or maybe the cell contains an error such as `#DIV/0!` or some different error. Or maybe the cell contains some text instead of a number? All of these would explain why `sVal1` cannot be assigned the value of that cell during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following solution can be of help:

```
Sub test411()

Dim wsUp As Worksheet
Dim wsEntry As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long, iCount As Long
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer

Set wsUp = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsEntry = Worksheets("Entries")

For iRow = 6 To 7
    lastrow = wsUp.Cells(wsUp.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    wsEntry.Activate
    iCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsEntry.Range(wsEntry.Cells(iRow, 4), wsEntry.Cells(iRow, 11)), ">0")
    wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1, "A" & lastrow + iCount).Value = wsEntry.Cells(5, 4).Value
    For iCol = 5 To 11
        If Cells(iRow, iCol) > "0" Then
            lastrow = wsUp.Cells(wsUP.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            wsUp.Range("A" & lastrow + 1, "A" & lastrow + 2).Value = wsEntry.Cells(5, iCol).Value
            wsUp.Cells("I", lastrow).Value = wsEntry.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        End If
    Next iCol
Next iRow

End Sub
```

Explanation: instead of assigning the values of cells to a variable and then using this variable to set another cell, I took the short route and immediately set the final cell to the value of the original cell (without a variable in between). Like this you don't have to worry about Excel VBA variables and data types.

Comment: Good one Ralph !

Comment: Don't forget to qualify the `Cells()` lines in the `iCount = ...` line, and the `Rows.Count` too.

Comment: @BruceWayne Good catch. Next time, feel free to just edit my post and do it yourself.